# Functors with ability of "reduction in the formulas"

Tags: logic, soft-question, category-theory

I am interesting about next class of functors. Let $F : \mathbf{C} \to \mathbf{K}$ - functor between categories. And let $P(f_1,...,f_n)$ predicate in abstract category first-order language. And functor $F$ has next property: $P(f_1,...,f_n) \leftrightarrow P(F(f_1), F(f_2), ..., F(f_n))$. In other words $P$ is true on a tuple $(f_1,...,f_n)$ in $\mathbf{C}$ iff $P$ is true on a tuple $(F(f_1),...,F(f_n))$ in $\mathbf{K}$. Thats why, for example, $f$ isomorphism/monomorphism/coretraction iff $F(f)$ has the same type. What we know about that functors? Do they have a name?

Comment: These are the elementary embeddings of categories.

Comment: What is the first-order language you are using for categories? And is your $P(f_1, \ldots, f_n)$ an atomic formula or an arbitrary formula?

Comment: @RobArthan see McLane 2.1 "Duality", language of "elementary theory of abstract category (ETAC)". Arbitrary formula, but it doesnt matter, I think ZhenLin was right and question is not interesting :3

Comment: Yes, "elementary embedding" is right given what you say.